# XP reports LAN cable unplugged, but internet still works?

Tags: networking, windows-xp

I am using Windows XP desktop. One day, the LAN icon started showing that the network cable was unplugged.  I have restarted the router and checked the cables. However, the internet works on my XP laptop so there is no issue in the cables or modem.

Sometimes, the LAN shows as connected but internet doesn't work, and there is no IP or DNS assigned to it.  I have tried entering the IP and DNS manually but it's still the same.  The Internet only works when i do a system restore on the desktop.  Once I restart the desktop, the internet connection shows that the cable is unplugged.  I have to keep restoring the system for the internet to work.

Comment: Typically this sort of issue is layer 1, meaning that it is a bad cable, switch port or NIC. First replace the cable, see if it continues. Then try a different switch port (try the one your laptop is in as you know that one works), and if the problem still persists, replace the NIC. If it still persists after that, you could be looking at a problem with your driver or configuration.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt network stack to me - otherwise a system restore wouldn't fix it.

Comment: I'm no network engineer, but I would definitely suspect the network adaptor and/or it's drivers...

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is reinstall the drivers for the Network Interface Card.

If that doesn't solve it, reset the TCP/IP protocol to see if that resolves a corrupted stack. [How to reset Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357)

If it still isn't resolved, try another network adapter if one is available. The NIC may be failing.